# Is there a way to reinstall SUBVERSIVE?

Tags: eclipse, subversive

I tried to uninstall Subversive within my Eclipse IDE as I updated Subversive yesterday after an Eclipse update was installed that only updated Subversive.

The update whacked all my function keys within Eclipse and therefore the reason to try and uninstall it. Apparently I've done something wrong and it did not uninstall it completely.  Here is the info I'm reading when trying to uninstall:

> Subversive SVN Team Provider" cannot be fully uninstalled because other installed software requires it.  The parts that are not required will be uninstalled.

I still click the uninstall button but it *never* uninstalls.

I've lost connection to the repository and I've been Googling for a way to reinstall Subversive but cannot find anything to accomplish that.

Any suggestions/direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unzip Eclipse to a new directory.  Install Subversive to that Eclipse.

Comment: I guess there is no way to reinstall to fix a problem with subversive.  I've reinstalled Eclipse and will start again.  Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Nope.  Eclipse is like Windows.  If you have a Windows problem, you reformat C: and reinstall.  If you have any Eclipse problem, you unzip Eclipse to a new directory and start over.  The end.

Answer (score 0):

Use this update-site: http://download.eclipse.org/technology/subversive/4.0/update-site/

It works for me on Eclipse 2020-12 (4.18.0)